# my lenovo laptop redirects to the bios screen and then beeps continuesly

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

my lenovo b570e laptop not booting,  it beeps and then displays bios and then continues beeping for as long as the available power can carry.  the only way to stop it is to press a key on the keyboard. it redirects to the bios setup screen

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Please provide some background to your issue.  What did you do before this problem started? How long have you had the laptop? What messages are displayed when the laptop starts? What do the beeps sound like; is there a pattern like two long-one short? Additional details will help us provide a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous beeps on startup usually implies bad RAM. Try to open your laptop and take out the RAM and put it back in.

If your problems continues use Memtest to test your RAM memory. If the tests fail than you know that you need to change your RAM. You can find Memtest [here](http://www.memtest.org/)